# SHELL: execution using variable

Tags: bash, shell

I write below statements in my .bashrc

```
alias ls='ls -l'
$LS = 'ls'
```

I expected `$LS` execute `ls -l` in command line prompt because `ls` already modified to `ls -l`. but `$LS` execute ls only `ls`.

`ls` execute `ls -l` because alias as below:

```
> ls
total 28
-rw-r--r--  1 chlee chlee    82  8월 30 22:07 '#test.py#'
drwxr-xr-x  2 chlee chlee  4096  8월 21 04:09  exer
-rw-r--r--  1 chlee chlee    64  8월 30 21:49  test.py
-rw-r--r--  1 chlee chlee    49  8월 30 21:47  test.py~
drwxr-xr-x 29 chlee chlee 12288  8월 21 02:51  vsdbg
```

`$LS` execute only `ls` as below:

```
> $LS
'#test.py#'   exer   test.py   test.py~   vsdbg
```

How can I get the shell to take into account aliases when variable evaluation?

Comment: You can't.  Aliases only expand the words that you actually type.  The solution, of course, is to modify your bashrc to say `LS='ls -l'`.  Note that you don't use the `$` when defining variables.  If you have that in your bashrc, you should delete it.

Comment: Use a `function` and all your problems will go away.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This should work as you expect:

```
#!/bin/bash

alias ls="ls -l"
LS () {
   ls
}

echo trying lower
ls
echo Trying upper
LS
```

The function is called `LS` including parses aliases.

```
# source LS.sh
trying lower
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 89 Sep 19 21:50 LS.sh
Trying upper
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 89 Sep 19 21:50 LS.sh
```

Jetchisel was pointing you to this in the comments.